# Print a JavaScript string as a string literal

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to print a string as a string literal in JavaScript, so that the string will be printed exactly as it is written:

```
printStringLiteral("\n\nHi!");//this prints "Hi!" instead of "\n\nHi!".
                              //What will I need to do in order to print
                              //the string as a string literal instead?

function printStringLiteral(toPrint){
    console.log("\"" toPrint + "\"");
}
```

Comment: It's likely that I'd only need to put an escape character (`\\`) before each character in the string - however, I haven't tested this solution yet.

Comment: No, if you had the string "no" and did that then the first character would be turned into a new line escape sequence.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, I'd need to find a different solution. :/

Comment: I don't think there is a way to convert a string back to its literal representation. A string is a sequence of Unicode code points, how would you know *how* the code was created (e.g. `\n` or `\u000A`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use JSON:

```
JSON.stringify(toPrint);
```

Comment: I was about to post this as an answer, but you beat me to it. :)

Comment: Here's an example on jsfiddle (and it works as intended!) http://jsfiddle.net/jarble/x2mSt/1/

Comment: I was just thinking about that, but it does not necessarily convert the string back to its literal form. E.g. `"\n\nHi!\u000A"` becomes `"\n\nHi!\n"`.

Comment: @FelixKling - Good point.  If you want the *actual* source code, you'd have to do an AJAX request for it.

Comment: Those are equivalent string literals. Information is lost when the source code is parsed, so you can't expect any better than that.

Comment: @Barmar - It's not completely lost though:  [jsfiddle.net/wECF5](http://jsfiddle.net/wECF5/).  JavaScript still knows about it internally.  I don't think there's a practical way to get it out, though (Short of `toString()` on the function on and ridiculous parsing).

Answer (score 0):

```
printStringLiteral("\\\n\\\nHi!");

function printStringLiteral(toPrint){
    console.log("\\\"" + toPrint + "\\\"");
}
```

Comment: The output of this function isn't correct - see here: http://jsfiddle.net/jarble/V6brF/2/

Comment: This answer require the original string to escape it's `\` chars, which is not what the OP asks.